# UPDATE нескольких строк

Tags: mysql, sql

Какой синтаксис у должен быть у UPDATE, чтобы изменить 3-6 строк в одной таблице ?

Comment: такой же как и обычно. Про слово WHERE что-нибудь слышали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET field1=4 WHERE field2>24 LIMIT 6
```

Устанавливает значение field1 равным 4 везде, где field2 больше 24. Максимум изменится 6 значений.

```
UPDATE table SET field1=field1+10 WHERE field2>24 LIMIT 6
```

Увеличивает на 10 значения всех field1 в строках, где field2 больше 24. Максимум изменится 6 значений.